# Was the date for the 9/11 attack chosen to be the same as the emergency number in the U.S. (911)?

Tags: united-states, 9-11

Many sites on the internet cite this coincidence as ether a prof to a conspiracy by the gov. or a message that the terrorists wanted to pass to the American People. Here are just some exmples from around the net:

[Yahoo Questions:](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100702012900AAvzSU1)

> Q: I just got wondering, is it a coincidence that the terrorist attacks on the WTC towers was on 9/11? The emergency number to dial in the US is 911 after all. I always thought the number was chosen after the attacks, but I just read it has existed for a few decades already.
>
> So, did the terrorists pick 9/11 on purpose because 911 is the US emergency phone number, or is this just a coincidence?

The accepted answer:

> Haven't you heard about the " the artificial accident of Pentagon " ???
>
> more often than not that it was a " fabricated " accident rather than a pure coincidence or even a proceed of a smart planning of so called " the terrorist and Bin Laden" ....they probably have cooperated with each other( US government with bin laden ) to make that tragedy ....Bin Laden has never presented Islam in any way ...
>
> actually you should rephrase that Q to this way: have ""US government" chosen that day deliberately?
>
> just google it and you will find thousand sites talking about this ...

And some of the other answers:

> A1: I always thought that. Their idea of a joke or something.
>
> A2: I don't believe in "coincidences."

[ask.com question:](http://www.ask.com/answers/118154081/does-the-emergency-number-911-have-anything-to-do-with-the-9-11-terrorist-attacks)

> Does the emergency number 911 have anything to do with the 9-11 terrorist attacks?

And one of the answers said:

> The emergency phone number 911 has been around for a very long time. I'm fairly sure the attacks occurred on 9/11 just to add insult to injury.

[From www.abovetopsecret.com:](http://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread634246/pg1)

> I was wondering of the coincidence or not of September 11 as called 9/11 & the emegency phone number for America being 911.
>
> 1. Was this just a coincidence?
> 2. Was this day chosen to teach America the fear of a real emergency from the "alledged" terrorist point of view?
> 3. Was this day chosen by the "alledged" TPTB to instill a date that could be easily remembered due to it being so close to an already well known number 911 phone number?
> 4. Was this day chosen to be an ironical slap in the face of the general populace?
>
> Just always seemed to much of a coincidence of 9/11 & 911 being chosen.
>
> I say this because many other countries use different dating systems for example 9/11/2001 is dated 11/9/2001.
>
> Also the 911 emergency phone number is differnet for other countries where numbers like 000 or 999 are used instead.
>
> Anyone ever thought this as too much of an ironical coincidence?

Many of the answers in that thread also think the same:

> A1: The date was absolutely chosen on purpose. Regardless of who you think did the deed, there was months 
>   if not years of planning that went into the 911attack. With all that must have gone into putting all that together, the numeric symbol is to apparent and powerful to be by chance.
>
> A2: Options 2,3 and 4 seem more likely than 1. But the number may be significant for other reasons. Numerology is extremely important to the Illuminati according to most of the people who study them. (How does one study a secret organization? Is it even organized enough to study?) Many of the sites google listed seem kooky, but something might make sense.

Comment: Actually 9/11 happened on 11/9 for most of the world ;-) But then again, for great part of the world emergency number is 112.

Comment: How did you get in your mental process from some coincidence to “this must be a cover up”?

Comment: How can it not be a coverup is the better question, there are 365 days a year, whats the odds that a terrorist bombing would occur on the same day as the emergency phone number in the same state where they use 911 to call the police.. You have to be crazy to not see this.

Comment: @SSpoke: you do understand what "cover up" means? And FYI, terrorist attacks are **not** random events.

Comment: i always thought that it was 11/9 as a biblical reference.  The fall of the tower of babel

Comment: A similiar question was asked on History SE and I came up with [a few more reasons why there's likely no symbolic significance to the date](http://history.stackexchange.com/a/19403/4615).

Comment: This is just the Law of small Numbers at play. Or recall that on 9/11 of 1714, Barcelona was conquered by Spain - the same Spain started the Reconquista!

Comment: @Andrey That actually makes more sense, if the date was chosen to be significant.

Comment: @SSpoke
"whats the odds... same day as the emergency phone number?"
They would want it to be a business day: 365 - (2*52) = 261 week days a year.

Remove holidays and and extra day to eliminate "long weekends" -- 10 federal holidays, so take another 20 days off: 261 - 20 = 241 "work days"

That leaves 1/241 odds that if the date was chosen at "random" it would land on 9/11. But, then, how many others days would also be attributed meaning had the attacks fell on them. 1/1, 2/2 (also DC's area code), 3/14 is Pi day, 4/20 is "weed day" (*SMH*), and so on.

Comment: It was actually chosen, or at least noted from an early stage, to be the same as the Porsche 911. Intelligence chatter was full of references to Porsche just before 9/11 but no-one seems to have connected it with a date. This very fact is now almost impossible to verify (I've just tried googling) although it was acknowledged at the time. Was it in the official 9/11 report?

Comment: Duplicate: https://history.stackexchange.com/q/16736

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No it wasn't, While the terrorists used the Gregorian calender to communicate the date of the attack, they used it in its form known throughout the rest of the world: dd/mm/yyyy and not the American form mm/dd/yyyy. So that it forms the 11/9 and not 9/11. Here is how Mohamed Atta transmitted the date of the attack to the operatives ([source](http://www.cbsnews.com/stories/2002/10/09/60ii/main524947.shtml)):

> As the Saudis were arriving in the U.S. in July, Atta was taking off, flying into Madrid and driving 500 miles to a Spanish coastal resort for a working vacation. Joining him was Ramzi Binalshibh with a message from Khalid Shaikh Mohammed. The final date for the operation was in Atta's hands. Atta had Shaikh Mohammed's complete trust.
>
> Then, on Aug. 29, the phone rang in Binalshibh's Hamburg apartment at three in the morning.
>
> It was Atta with an important, but cryptic message: "He said to me, 'One of my friends related a riddle to me and I cannot solve it, and I called you so that you can solve it for me.'" Binalshibh is heard saying.
>
> Atta goes, **"Two sticks, a dash and a cake with a stick down."**
>
> Binalshibh said, "I said to him, 'Is this the riddle? You wake me from a deep sleep to tell me this riddle? Two sticks and I do not know what?'"
>
> Eventually, Yosri Fouda says, Binalshibh realized what Atta meant. So he says to him, "OK. Tell your friend, he has nothing to worry about. It's such a sweet riddle."
>
> Binalshibh explained it: "The two sticks represent the number 11, then the dash, and then the cake from which a stick dangles represents number nine. Thus, the picture becomes complete: the 11th of September."
>
> Binalshibh left Hamburg on Wednesday, Sept. 5, for Pakistan. From there, he sent a messenger into Afghanistan with news for Khalid Shaikh Mohammed and Osama bin Laden: Tuesday, Sept. 11, would be the day.

Comment: I always thought it was "Therefore its name was called Babel, because there the Lord confused[a] the language of all the earth. And from there the Lord dispersed them over the face of all the earth" 11:9 Genesis

Comment: @Andrey, that's in the Bible though. I think they read from a different [playbook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel#Islamic_tradition).

Comment: This explains how the date was communicated. It does not explain why that date was chosen.

Comment: Genesis is part of the Torah though - Muslims do follow that playbook.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard But whatever the reason was (if there was any symbology behind it at all), the fact that it was communicated as "eleven nine" casts doubt on the suspicicion that "nine eleven" was specifically chosen in order to coincide with "nine one one".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But the planners of the attack must surely have known that in the U.S. the date would be read as "9-11".

Comment: @iamnotmaynard .. or "September eleven". While Ilya's answer gives no compelling hint for the *reason* to choose 2001-09-11, it certainly gives not the slightest hint for a relation to 9-1-1 in a situation where such reason *might* have mentioned. In the absence of any *supportive* hints anywhere, Occam's razor dictates: coincidence.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Then the answer would need to by "By Occam's Razor, no." Whether that would be correct, good, or convincing is another issue, but it would be _an_ answer to the question. I don't think this actually answers it.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard But the probability that a randomly chosen date happens to coincide with the emergency number 911 is very low, whereas the probability that terrorists would deliberately choose it (knowing its significance in the USA, the targeted nation) is non-negligible. So by Bayes' theorem, the probability that it was deliberately chosen is indeed high.

Comment: @M.Vinay I'm not really sure that is quite as meaningful as you're implying.  There are a whole lot of numbers that could be randomly that might look "meaningful" after the fact.  If it had happened on November 9th you could make the same argument.  (dd/mm format)  If you try to make numbers match after the fact, you can often find matches if you try hard enough: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/20684/13217

Comment: @PatrickM And in *each* of those cases, it *is* more likely that that date was deliberately chosen. Bayes' theorem applies in each case. Regarding the link, Quran's "predicting" the speed of light is in itself a highly unlikely event, a priori (unlike the probability that someone chooses a date of some specific significance). So the same Bayes' theorem tells us that it is unlikely a posteriori as well.

Comment: @PatrickM Actually, I am not completely decided on this myself. I have to think on it a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

From [Lawrence Wright’s 2006 Pulitzer Prize-winning book “The Looming Tower”](http://brock911.wikia.com/wiki/The_Looming_Tower:Chapter_8):

> To them, the Crusades were a continual historical process that would
>   never be resolved until the final victory of Islam. They bitterly
>   perceived the contradiction embodied by Islam's long, steady retreat
>   from the gates of Vienna, where **on September 11 — that now resonant
>   date — in 1683, the king of Poland began the battle that turned back the
>   farthest advance of Muslim armies**. For the next three hundred years,
>   Islam would be overshadowed by the growth of Western Christian
>   societies. Yet bin Laden and his Arab Afghans believed that, in
>   Afghanistan, they had turned the tide and that Islam was again on the
>   march.

[Christoppher Hitchens had the same idea](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2001/oct/03/september11.usa2):

> I now think I can provide a more persuasive explanation, however. **It
>   was on September 11 1683 that the conquering armies of Islam were met,
>   held, and thrown back at the gates of Vienna.**
>
> [...]
>
> In our culture, the episode is often forgotten or downplayed, except
>   by Catholic propagandists like Hilaire Belloc and GK Chesterton. But
>   in the Islamic world, and especially among the extremists, it is
>   remembered as a humiliation in itself and a prelude to later ones.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) It's interesting to hear this hypothesis from these two journalists, but it isn't clear whether this is just speculation on their behalf, or if they have evidence to support that (a) September 11 *is* an important  occasion amongst the Islamic world, and (b) the date was chosen for the attacks for that reason. If you are allowed to look back in history for over 300 years, it is likely you can find some significant anniversary on any day of the year.

Comment: While I might like to see more proof (e.g. some quotes from the islamic world that this is indeed true) it is an interesting idea.

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=SWBkx0UlgMAC&pg=PA216&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) states that the battle was on September 12.